# CDH 5.3 won't boot after switching from NAT to bridged networking

Tags: linux, hadoop, ssh, cloudera, cloudera-cdh

I've downloaded the cloudera-quickstart-vm-5.3.0-0-virtualbox.7z virtualbox image and started it.  Hadoop was running.  I could ping from guest to host, but not from host to guest (fairly common one-way ping problem).  I also could not connect ssh from host to guest even though sshd was running on the guest (CentOS 6.4).

I downloaded a couple of data files in *.txt.gz format to the guest (CentOS 6.4).  When I uncompressed them the *.txt files were garbage.  I did the same on my host OS (Ubuntu 14) and the files were fine.

I shutdown CDH and changed to bridged networking and now when I reboot CentOS guest it hangs after several minutes showing the progress bar at 100% and "CentOR 6.4" showing in the bottom right.

Is there a fix for this problem or is the CDH 5.3 virtualbox image just broken?

Comment: Confirmed that it is the bridged networking that causes the boot to hang.  Switched back to NAT and it is working again.  Still have the one-way ping problem.  I can connect ssh from guest (CentOS 6.4) to host (Ubuntu 14), but not vice-versa.

Comment: You might have more luck if you retarget the question as "CentOS on Virtualbox won't boot after switching from NAT to bridged networking".